# Optimizing a simple query on a large table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, optimization

DB: MySQL 5.5.20 (WampServer, default configuration)
OS: Win 7
HDD: Western Digital 3TB Caviar Green, 3.5", IntelliPower, 64MB, Sata3 (WD30EZRX)
Memory: 8GB
MySQL my.ini: http://pastie.org/private/go9kaxlmlvirati2txbaa

Query in question:

> SELECT name.id AS name_id, name.name, cast_info.id,
>   cast_info.role_id, cast_info.movie_id
>   FROM cast_info
>   LEFT JOIN name ON name.id = cast_info.person_id
>   WHERE cast_info.movie_id = 1000000
>   ORDER BY cast_info.movie_id ASC

It fetches all people who worked on a given movie. Problem is it can take anywhere from 0.1s to nearly 2.0s. That's too long. When the user needs to run it 10k times they might as well uninstall the application. Even I haven't had the patience to wait for it to finish.

edit: The time it takes to run the query is determined by the number of people who worked on it. Roughly 0.1s for each 10 people.

EXPLAIN:

> *************************** 1. row ***************************
>              id: 1
>     select_type: SIMPLE
>           table: cast_info
>            type: ref
>   possible_keys: idx_mid,mpi
>             key: idx_mid
>         key_len: 4
>             ref: const
>            rows: 15
>           Extra:
>   *************************** 2. row ***************************
>              id: 1
>     select_type: SIMPLE
>           table: name
>            type: eq_ref
>   possible_keys: PRIMARY,id_name_idx
>             key: PRIMARY
>         key_len: 4
>             ref: imdb.cast_info.person_id
>            rows: 1
>           Extra:

Tables:

> CREATE TABLE `cast_info` (
>    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>    `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>    `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>    `person_role_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>    `note` text,
>    `nr_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>    `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>    KEY `idx_pid` (`person_id`),
>    KEY `idx_mid` (`movie_id`),
>    KEY `idx_cid` (`person_role_id`),
>    KEY `cast_info_role_id_exists` (`role_id`),
>    KEY `mpi` (`movie_id`,`person_id`,`id`)
>   ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=33261692 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
>
> CREATE TABLE `name` (
>    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>    `name` varchar(110) NOT NULL,
>    `imdb_index` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
>    `imdb_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>    `gender` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
>    `name_pcode_cf` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
>    `name_pcode_nf` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
>    `surname_pcode` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
>    `md5sum` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
>    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>    KEY `idx_name` (`name`(6)),
>    KEY `idx_imdb_id` (`imdb_id`),
>    KEY `idx_pcodecf` (`name_pcode_cf`),
>    KEY `idx_pcodenf` (`name_pcode_nf`),
>    KEY `idx_pcode` (`surname_pcode`),
>    KEY `idx_md5` (`md5sum`),
>    KEY `id_name_idx` (`id`,`name`)
>   ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4287972 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Thanks!

edit: MyISAM is used because this is a local database, used by one local application, by one user. Only one query is executed at the same time. Also because IMDbPy takes at least a month to build the database with InnoDB...

edit: Query EXPLAIN after converting to InnoDB:

> *************************** 1. row ***************************
>              id: 1
>     select_type: SIMPLE
>           table: cast_info
>            type: ref
>   possible_keys: mpi
>             key: mpi
>         key_len: 3
>             ref: const
>            rows: 23
>           Extra:
>   *************************** 2. row ***************************
>              id: 1
>     select_type: SIMPLE
>           table: name
>            type: eq_ref
>   possible_keys: PRIMARY,id_name_idx
>             key: PRIMARY
>         key_len: 4
>             ref: imdb.cast_info.person_id
>            rows: 1
>           Extra:

Comment: What are your settings for `key_buffer_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would run faster with InnoDB,

- The `PRIMARY KEY` is 'clustered'; this makes the lookup into `name` faster.
- A suitable setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` of, say, 5G (for your 8GB machine) would cache a lot of stuff, thereby minimizing the I/O for 10K operations.

You could also shrink the data (and decrease the I/O) by using `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` or `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` where appropriate.

There are redundant indexes that could (should) be removed; this would speed up the load.  Also `name(6)` is probably useless.

Comment: I converted all possible fields to MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED and one to TINYINT UNSIGNED. I don't think that changed anything. I could remove some indexes but not sure which. For instance the `mpi` index was recommended to me on freenode's #mysql channel for this exact query. Are indexes helpful if I only need a field for the SELECT x,y,z part and not JOINs or WHERE?

Comment: Indexes mostly help with `WHERE`, but they can help with `JOIN` and `ORDER BY`.  `mpi` is a "covering index", meaning that the index (a separate BTree) provides all the columns needed for the query.  Your `EXPLAIN` does not show it using that index.  DROP INDEX idx_mid; to see if it helps.

Comment: I dropped idx_mid. Converted all tables to InnoDB. I can't set innodb_buffer_pool_size above 2G so it's at 2G. And the query became slower :/

Comment: Please provide the `EXPLAIN` after converting to InnoDB.

Comment: Added to first post. Rows differs because I might've used another movie_id earlier.

Comment: Oops...  `mpi` is _not_ covering.  The `SELECT` also includes `role_id`.  Adding that to the end of the mpi index should get it "covering"; the `EXPLAIN` will confirm it by saying `Using index`.

Comment: Thanks! It's a bit faster now. It's tolerable. I managed to run the application now for the first time! It basically imports my imdb ratings and displays a list of every person (actors, directors, writers, etc) I've seen at least one film from and what my progress is.

Answer (score 1):

I saw query then explain and then table definition and first question came into my mind. Why are you still on MyISAM @ 5.5? Let's just change this to InnoDB and you should get the results. 
This 0.1 to 2 range could be caused by locks or other reasons but let's avoid that issue first?

Be-aware that below conversion will lock the tables and may cause downtime.

`alter table cast_info engine=innodb;`

`alter table name engine=innodb;`

Comment: Why MyISAM? 1) Building the database with InnoDB takes such a ridiculous amount of time nobody has time for it so MyISAM is the only option here. 2) This is a local database only ever used by a single local application by one user. Ever. So only one query is executed at a time. No two queries are ever executed at the same time. So I don't see how a lock could be causing this? 3) I've already tried converting the tables to InnoDB, nothing changed. In fact, the query took even longer to execute so I converted back to MyISAM.

Comment: To add to #2 in the previous comment: I've taken those measurements when no other application was running. The database was completely idle. And I can replicate them every time. So again, not an issue with locks...

Comment: 1) I'd take initial pain to get things right later. 2) would you post my.ini? As such the query plan looks good.... let me retry... 3) What was innodb buffer pool when you converted it last time?

Comment: You might also like to debug with `set profiling =1` `show profile for query X`

Comment: @TheMagician ad 1) - using InnoDB instead of MyISAM for your tables means just naming a different engine in your create table statements, there is not much "design time" difference to make it into a *"a ridiculous amount of time"* - If you meant foreign keys and stuff, thats still optional (even when I would suggest to set them properly)

Comment: @jkavalik: The database is built by IMDbPy. You can either select MyISAM or InnoDB for tables. With InnoDB, after 1 hour, it was still processing A's in the first file (there's 18 files in my case). I stopped it, dropped all tables, and selected MyISAM. After 50 minutes it was done with all 18 files. To quote IMDbPy website: "InnoDB is abysmal slow for our purposes: my suggestion is to always use MyISAM tables and - if you really want to use InnoDB - convert the tables later." Abysmal slow indeed!

Comment: @mysql_user: I've added my.ini to the first post. I also explained what determines the query execution time. To answer your #3: Whatever the defaults were. They seem to be comments in the my.ini file... Also #1: Not gonna happen with InnoDB, see my comment above. EDIT: Also converting these tables to InnoDB takes a long time: 7.5hours for cast_info table. But only 10 minutes to convert back to MyISAM.

Comment: Sounds like IMDbPy needs some help with tuning, keys, etc.

Comment: Well I'd **convert all to innodb after imdbpy finishes and back it up.** at this point innodb will give you best performance boost and then some variable tuning....                               Also better tune *atleast* buffers to start with before complaining performance. Convert innodb set bufferpool to atleast 4-6G and then see the perf. This may not be dedicated box as well!! +1 for imdbpy help @rick.....

Comment: @TheMagician, ah, so thats what you mean with "building", then the suggestion to *"convert the tables later"* is probably really a good one, use the alters as mysql_user suggests. The scripts is maybe not using transactions properly so thats why its slow..

Answer (score 1):

Performance is consistent with the hard drive, you shall consider getting an SSD or even better, a RAID system. Your drive is a slow desktop class hard driver, totally not fit for database work. Try testing with a 7200 rpm desktop, and you will already see improvements. If the People table is so large that it does not fit into RAM (cached by OS, not loaded in user memory), physical non-sequential access to the hard drive is the problem of your performance.

Since you don't run a "true" database, but you ship the data to the customer in a desktop application, a quick solution would be to de-normalize and add a redundant field "cast_data" on Movie, with all your needed data as a JSON. Updating such a structure will be difficult if performed in any other way than on movie (for example update the birthday of a cast), but data will be retrieved very fast, no matter the storage.

Answer (score 0):

A few questions/observations:

1. Why are you sorting the result on `cast_info.movie_id` when the WHERE clause only allows for a single `movie_id`?
2. Likewise, why are you returning the `movie_id` in the result: it is going to be the same in every row.

Try creating a composite index on `cast_info(movie_id, person_id)`.

I expect that would be much, much better.